# How to change the color of Eclipse RCP view title bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How to change the color of Eclipse RCP view title bar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the color with this is possible with the **[org.eclipse.ui.themes Extension-Point](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_themes.html)**.

Here's an example snippet

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.themes">
      <theme
            id="de.spiritlink.custom.ui.theme"
            name="Custom Theme">
         <colorOverride
               id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_END"
               value="255,0,0">
         </colorOverride>
         <colorOverride
               id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_START"
               value="0,255,0">
         </colorOverride>
      </theme>
   </extension>
```

Setting the theme programmatically with [**IThemeManager**](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/themes/IThemeManager.html), which is an object that contains references to usable **[`ITheme`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/themes/ITheme.html)** objects and maintains a reference to the currently active theme. This theme will be used by the workbench to decorate tab folders and other controls where possible:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager().setCurrentTheme("myThemeID");
```

Other details in thoses articles:

- [Adding Color and Font preferences](http://swik.net/Eclipse/Eclipse+Tips/Adding+Color+and+Font+preferences/cqkx3)
- [**RCP Custom Look and Feel**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel)